# ASP.NET MVC layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have layout page and the page that uses layout.
How can I add some new elements to the head not changing layout.(layout already contains head)?

Layout:

```
<head>...</head>
```

I want my page be like:

```
<head>all layout head logic... plus
     my page new elements...
     </head>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use sections in the layout. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

and then in the view override this section and provide contents for it:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('hello');
    </script>
}

<div>Hello from the index view</div>
```

And since the section is optional (second argument = false) if a view doesn't provide any contents for it, it will stay empty.